GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "unable to get local issuer certificate"
I have attempted to reinstall GitHub Copilot, but the output remains unchanged. Additionally, I have restarted Visual Studio Code, yet the problem persists. I have also checked the official documentation and forums for any known issues or solutions, but to no avail. Furthermore, I have ensured that my system meets all the requirements for GitHub Copilot, including having the latest version of Visual Studio Code and a stable internet connection. Despite these efforts, the problem continues to elude me.


Try to update versions
Try to reconfigure within Extensions.

If possible elaborate your problem with precise.
